# How high is the damage reduction from gunzerking with the skill come at me bro?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the Brawn skill tree from Salvador (Gunzerker) there is a skill called "Come At Me Bro" that has the following description:

> Action Skill Augment. While Gunzerking, taunt your enemies and instantly gain Full Health. Taunted enemies are more likely to attack you, but for the next few seconds you gain massive damage reduction. NEXT LEVEL: "Nigh Invulnerability is a hell of a drug."

Now I am interested how high the damage reduction is (though the red text says "Nigh Invulnerability" I assume that it will be very high) and how long it does stay active.

Comment: Gearbox - masters of pointless ambiguity.

Comment: Ambiguity leads to curiosity, which leads to new ways of doing stuff = more fun, more satisfaction through creativity.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line?  Not enough.  I do not have the exact % in front of me at the moment but I will look tomorrow and edit this to include any reliable info i find online. I wasted a lot of time and points in the red tree on my gunzerker and in the end he was still getting mowed down by lv 37 bandits (not badasses or armored either, just regular bandits) when he was 45 and had some very impressive gear, both legendary and just rare purples and such.  I found him to be far better at just pouring out lead with the blue tree and using a group to stay alive.

Comment: `I wasted a lot of time and points in the red tree` Well that's why there's Respec :) At low level I usually stick to the tree I want *right now* and respec into skills I think I'll like when I can actually try them out. No harm no foul either way though.

Comment: really?  level 37 bandits should be doing almost no damage to a level 45 due to the way level damage scales.